# Long-term effects of Vestibular Neuritis

Tags: nervous-system, vertigo, inner-ear

The symptoms of Vestibular Neuritis (VN) are known to lessen or disappear over a much longer period of time than, say, a typical headache or migraine. I know that there are at least potential long term effects; an NCBI bookshelf entry on VN [says](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK549866/):

> The natural history of this disease is uncomplicated with complete resolution in most cases. Some can have incomplete resolution and with a study showing 15% with persistent symptoms at one year.

and also:

> Two important complications associated with vestibular neuritis are benign paroxysmal positional vertigo (BPPV) and persistent postural-perceptual dizziness (PPPD)...  Research has found that 10 to 15% of patients with vestibular neuritis will develop BPPV in the affected ear within a few weeks.[11][12] ... One study found PPPD in 25% of patients who were followed 3 to 12 months after acute or episodic vestibular disorders.[14]

but I'm not satisfied with this description... it describes observed symptoms rather than causes inside the body. Another web page [mentions](https://www.betterbalanceinlife.com/vestibular-neuritis-recovery-tips/) hypofunction of the affected nerve, and the brain's adjustment to this hypofunction which may be difficult to undo - but in only a sentence or two, with little detail.

So, can you describe - in some detail if possible - the long-term effects of a spell of (non-HSV-induced) Vestibular Neuritis?

Comment: It seems like your question bounces between two things: mechanisms of this condition, and consequences/long-term effects. These things need not be particularly related in medicine (that is, one might know a mechanism, yet knowing that mechanism is not particularly useful in determining long term effects; alternatively, one could know long-term effects while having no clue whatsoever as to the mechanisms involved). Which are you looking for an answer on?

Comment: Well, eventually, effects. But saying "there's a 15% chance of having vertigo" sounds like you're buying a lottery ticket.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with that? I'm not really familiar with this condition but it seems very straightforward to have a study that shows that - you have 100 people with VN and follow them over time for a bit and find 15/100 develop vertigo - how is that not legitimate information to know? Certainly more straightforward than understanding *why*, especially in human patients.

Comment: @BryanKrause: What's wrong with that is that: 1. It doesn't tell us what actually happens with the nerves and the brain in those cases, and more importantly, 2. It doesn't characterize those 15% of cases and 3. It doesn't tell us what can be done to mitigate that risk.

Comment: Those would all be separate questions. It's very easy to not know any of those answers yet have plenty of data about the incidence.